# Exception building tensorflow 2 gpu from source: pyconfig.h no such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, bazel

I'm using a server with ubuntu 16, and have python 3.6 installed for my user

after installing cuda 10, cudnn7 and other required packages as root, I cloned tensorflow 2 beta from github and successfully ran the `./configure` command.
However, when I try to build the source with bazel (as regular user) 
(with this command: `bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`)
I get the following error

> ERROR:
>   /misc/home/thisuser/.cache/bazel/_bazel_thisuser/c065c6438711f6aa7a5cb8d6f2f657a0/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:670:1:
>   C++ compilation of rule
>   '@protobuf_archive//:python/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.so'
>   failed (Exit 1): crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error
>   executing command   (cd
>   /misc/home/thisuser/.cache/bazel/_bazel_thisuser/c065c6438711f6aa7a5cb8d6f2f657a0/execroot/org_tensorflow
>   && \   exec env - \
>       PATH=/home/thisuser/Python-3.6.3/bin:/home/thisuser/Python-3.6.3:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/thisuser/bin:/opt/jdk/bin
>   \
>       PWD=/proc/self/cwd \   external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc
>   -MD -MF bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/_objs/python/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.so/api_implementation.pic.d
>   '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/_objs/python/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.so/api_implementation.pic.o'
>   -iquote external/protobuf_archive -iquote bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive -iquote
>   external/local_config_python -iquote
>   bazel-out/host/bin/external/local_config_python -iquote
>   external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/host/bin/external/bazel_tools
>   -isystem external/local_config_python/python_include -isystem bazel-out/host/bin/external/local_config_python/python_include
>   '-std=c++11' -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"'
>   '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -fPIC
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -fno-omit-frame-pointer -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -DNDEBUG -g0 -O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g0 '-march=native' -g0 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DHAVE_ZLIB -Wall -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-function -Wno-write-strings -DPYTHON_PROTO2_CPP_IMPL_V2 -c external/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.cc
>   -o bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/_objs/python/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.so/api_implementation.pic.o)
>   Execution platform: @bazel_tools//platforms:host_platform In file
>   included from
>   external/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.cc:31:0:
>   bazel-out/host/bin/external/local_config_python/python_include/Python.h:8:22:
>   fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated. Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
>   failed to build INFO: Elapsed time: 169.767s, Critical Path: 30.68s
>   INFO: 2251 processes: 2251 local. FAILED: Build did NOT complete
>   successfully

Comment: I suspect this is related to missing python headers on your system. Did you install the `python-dev` package as instructed in here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#install_python_and_the_tensorflow_package_dependencies

Comment: @gunan that may have been the case. However, since then the administrator installed tensorflow-gpu system wide, and it's less of a priority for me now to verify what was the issue.